# How to fix the bash az-command not found

Tags: linux, bash, azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

I am trying to install Azure CLI on my raspberry pi 3 which runs Linux OS. I followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-linux?pivots=apt), but it gives me this `error: bash az-command not found`. I search online and found no solution to this error.

Comment: maybe you can paste screenshot or text of the error message.include what you input

Comment: Did you do as it says, and `apt install azure-cli`?

Comment: I tried to sudo apt-get update and i think there are some errors such as : Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/dists/buster/I                                                                             nRelease  Could not connect to packages.microsoft.com:443 (52.230.121.169). - co                                                                             nnect (113: No route to host)

Comment: I tried to do sudo apt install azure-cli but it give me this error: Unable to locate package azure-cli

Comment: Did you follow [Option 1: or Option 2:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-linux?pivots=apt)

Comment: Maybe this link will be useful: https://jimbobbennett.dev/blogs/az-cli-rpi/

Answer (score -1):

To install Azure CLI, the simplest way is to follow the steps in the link provided. But it seems you use the second way. So you can't run the command `apt install azure-cli` directly. You need to prepare the dependencies for the Azure CLI. And you also need to make sure if your network is OK. In the end, I recommend you use the first way that runs the shell script.

Answer (score -1):

I am facing the exact problem. i did "docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli"  without the quotation marks

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32472435)